# Showing only 1 row in crystal report details, when filling without dataset

Tags: c#, parameters, field, crystal-reports-2008

I am using parameter fields to make a report using Visual Studio 2008 with C# and Crystal Reports. I am trying to add multiple data in the parameter fields, but when i run the report i can see only one row.

I use this code to add multiple values to a String parameter field called smena in Details section.

```
            ReportDocument rptDnevenManuelna = new ReportDocument();
            rptDnevenManuelna.Load(Server.MapPath("~/crptDnevenManuelna.rpt"));

            ParameterField smena_field = rptDnevenManuelna.ParameterFields["smena"];
            smena_field.CurrentValues.Clear();
            smena_field.EnableAllowMultipleValue = true;

            ParameterDiscreteValue smena_value = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
            smena_value.Value = "1";
            smena_field.CurrentValues.Add(smena_value);

            smena_value = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
            smena_value.Value = "2";
            smena_field.CurrentValues.Add(smena_value);

            crvDnevenManuelna.ReportSource = rptDnevenManuelna;
```

Also i tried using this code:

```
rptDnevenManuelna.SetParameterValue("smena", new String[] { "1", "2", "3" });
```

And tried like this:

```
rptDnevenManuelna.SetParameterValue("smena","1");
rptDnevenManuelna.SetParameterValue("smena","2");
```

When i debug the last row of my code "crvDnevenManuelna.ReportSource = rptDnevenManuelna;" i can clearly see that in rptDnevenManuelna -> ParameterFields -> [0] -> Current Values -> Count = 2, this parameter field have 2 values. When my report is displayed i can see only the first row. In the designer view i set this parameter field to allow multiple values. I think that my error should be in the design of the report because when i reset my report before showing it, i can put multiple values in the field "smena" and still after submit i get only one row.

Answer (score 0):

You have a record filter in you report? Do you use "=" or "in" in your filter?